# JMeter: Why page keeps on loading continuously while recording using https?

Tags: https, jmeter, recording

The application is built using .Net and there is no issue when accessing the website manually. The issue is while recording and the page keeps on loading which won't display any objects.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

In the majority of cases it should be enough to import JMeter's certificate into your browser:

1. Locate `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file (it is being generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you start [JMeter's Proxy Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf))
2. Import the certificate into JMeter. The steps differ from browser to browser so check out your browser documentation for details. You can also find example steps in the **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) JMeter User Manual entry
3. Restart JMeter, clear your browser data (history, cache, etc.) and repeat your recording attempt.

Check out [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server) for more detailed instructions and some troubleshooting tips.

If it does't work:

- check *jmeter.log* file for any suspicious entries
- open "network" tab of your browser's developer tools and see what is the reason for certain requests failue
- consider alternative recording solution, i.e. [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en)